# In Altium Designer, how do I change the radius during interactive arc routing?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

In Altium Designer, how do I change the radius during interactive arc routing?
Here the radius is 100mil, but I need it tighter.

[image: Altium Interactive Arc Routing Radius]

Comment: Try pressing Tab while routing, or if you've already routed it, right click and select "Properties".

Comment: If I recall correctly (I don't have AD here) "," and "." are the keys that control the radius (It might be "<" and ">" but I recall that as being something else?).

Answer (score 1):

I tried ';' and '.' on Danish keyboard and that successfully changed the default radius!